# Powershell v2.0 - SQL query not returning the date

Tags: t-sql, powershell

I have a SQL command from within a PS script to return a datetime field. The SQL script works as expected if run within SQL Studio Manager, but if I run within Powershell it just "counts" the number of records, in this case "1".

```
$SqlCmd.CommandText = 
"SELECT q.execution_queued_timestamp
FROM [database].[dbo].[Execution_Queue] AS q
LEFT JOIN [database].[dbo].[Execution_Queue_Lock] AS l
ON l.lock_id = q.lock_id
WHERE execution_status_code = 'q'" 
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlConnection.Close()
$DataSet.Tables[0]
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SQL = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
```

So instead of getting a datetime format as I do in SQL SM, I get "1" in Powershell.

A similar behaviour is seen if the original T-SQL is "Select *", it instead outputs the number of records instead of the listing the actual matches.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for your data in the $DataSet object.  I usually use something like

```
foreach ($row in $DataSet.Tables[0].rows) { $row.execution_queued_timestamp }
```

but you should be able to go directly to the 1 returned element with something like this (untested)

```
 $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].execution_queued_timestamp
```

$SQL as you're using it will always have the number of rows returned.  You can ignore that if you don't care about the number of returned rows by changing that line to

```
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) |out-null
```

Comment: This one helped me thanks!$DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].execution_queued_timestamp